# How to parallelize groupby operation in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, parallel-processing

I have my original dataframe of size `4779657 (rows) and 26(columns)`.

Please find the code for sample dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'subject_id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4],
'readings' : ['READ_1','READ_2','READ_1','READ_3','READ_1','READ_5','READ_6','READ_8','READ_10','READ_12','READ_11','READ_14','READ_09','READ_08','READ_07'],
'val' :[5,6,7,11,5,7,16,12,13,56,32,13,45,43,46],
})
```

sample dataframe looks like as shown below

[image]

I would like to perform the below operation (long to wide). Out of 26 columns(in real data), I am trying to use the `3 columns in groupby` clause. thank you @jezrael for helping me reach upto this level

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['subject_id','readings'])['val']
    .describe()
    .unstack()
    .swaplevel(0,1,axis=1)
    .reindex(df['readings'].unique(), axis=1, level=0))
df1.columns = df1.columns.map('_'.join)
df1 = df1.reset_index()
```

The above code produces an output like shown below which is in line with my expected output. Only problem is the performance on large dataset

[image]

It's been more than half an hour and the code is still running. My system info is `8 GB installed RAM` and processor is `Intel Core i5-2500 CPU@3.30 GHZ` if knowing this can help anyway

Can you help me make this code efficient?

Comment: You should look at [Dask](https://dask.org/)

Comment: Try first converting any string columns to categories/factors, groupby should improve performance considerably

Comment: All my columns are numeric/integer/float datatypes. There aren't any string columns in my dataset

Comment: The above shown screenshot is an example. My real data has numeric ids for readings instead of `read_1,read_2` etc